# How can I schedule a particular file to store on EBS volume in AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, logging, amazon-ec2

I wonder if it is possible to store only a particular zipped file from my EC2 Instance to an EBS Volume? I know that there is an option to schedule a snapshot for EC2 Instance but I only need to backup one file every 30 minutes. The file is automatically generated on a location, I just need to watch it and copy on an EBS volume as soon as it is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do, is mount an ebs volume on a specific folder and then use that folder to save the zip you want snapshotted. 
Then you can schedule the ebs volume to be snapshotted periodically